# Inject mock class into method to unit test method

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to unit test a method which has a dependency on another class. The method calls a class method on that class, essentially this:

```
func myMethod() {

     //do stuff
     TheirClass.someClassMethod()

}
```

Using dependency injection technique, I would like to be able to replace "TheirClass" with a mock, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is there some way to pass in a mock *class* (not instance)?

EDIT: Thanks for the responses. Perhaps I should have provided more detail. The class method I am trying to mock is in an open source library.

Below is my method. I am trying to test it, while mocking out the call to `NXOAuth2Request.performMethod`. This class method issues a network call to get the authenticated user's info from our backend. In the closure, I am saving this info to the global account store provided by the open source library, and posting notifications for success or failure.

```
func getUserProfileAndVerifyUserIsAuthenticated() {

    //this notification is fired when the refresh token has expired, and as a result, a new access token cannot be obtained
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "didFailToGetAccessTokenNotification", name: NXOAuth2AccountDidFailToGetAccessTokenNotification, object: nil)

    let accounts = self.accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(UserAuthenticationScheme.sharedInstance.accountType) as Array<NXOAuth2Account>
    if accounts.count > 0 {
        let account = accounts[0]

        let userInfoURL = UserAuthenticationScheme.sharedInstance.userInfoURL

        println("getUserProfileAndVerifyUserIsAuthenticated: calling to see if user token is still valid")
        NXOAuth2Request.performMethod("GET", onResource: userInfoURL, usingParameters: nil, withAccount: account, sendProgressHandler: nil, responseHandler: { (response, responseData, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                println("User Info Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("UserCouldNotBeAuthenticated", object: self)
            }
            else if let data = responseData {
                var errorPointer: NSError?
                let userInfo = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &errorPointer) as NSDictionary

                println("Retrieved user info")
                account.userData = userInfo

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("UserAuthenticated", object: self)
            }
            else {
                println("Unknown error retrieving user info")
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("UserCouldNotBeAuthenticated", object: self)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Dependency injection, your class should have a constructor that accepts `TheirClass`.

Comment: How do I pass a class versus an instance of a class?

Comment: The constructor should accept an instance in which you will pass the mock object.

Comment: I can't use a mock instance because the method that I must call on the real object is a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: If the class method does not have global state or produces side effects then just focus on unit testing the static method and you won't need to test it inside of `myMethod`. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5757/is-static-universally-evil-for-unit-testing-and-if-so-why-does-resharper-recom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift this is better done by passing a function. There are many ways to approach this, but here is one:

```
func myMethod(completion: () -> Void = TheirClass.someClassMethod) {
    //do stuff
    completion()
}
```

Now you can pass a completion handler, while existing code will continue to use the default method. Notice how you can refer to the function itself (`TheirClass.someClassMethod`). You don't have to wrap it up in a closure.

You may find it better to let the caller just pass this all the time rather than making it a default. That would make this class less bound to `TheirClass`, but either way is fine.

It's best to integrate this kind of loose coupling, design-for-testability into the code itself rather than coming up with clever ways to mock things. In fact, you should ask yourself if `myMethod()` should really be calling `someClassMethod()` at all. Maybe these things should be split up to make them more easily tested, and then tie them together at a higher level. For instance, maybe `myMethod` should be returning something that you can then pass to `someClassMethod()`, so that there is no state you need to worry about.

Comment: Hello Rob, I came across this solution by looking for something very similar, In my case I have a slightly different problem, because the static method I should test accepts also a parameter, how could I work this around?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Rewrite the method to accept a closure that accepts a parameter. It's the same thing.

Comment: My problem was with the default value and with obj-c interoperability, if you have some time to spend, I asked a question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170690/mocking-a-static-class-method-in-a-swift-unit-test-in-a-swifty-way

Comment: Lovely solution, but I have a question about chaining these together. Say I want to test hisMethod() that calls myMethod(), but I want to inject that myMethod() to be replaced by a custom implementation. When adding the new myMethod as a parameter to hisMethod, I must specify the input parameters, but I can't omit the parameter that has a default, namely the injected method into myMethod. Must I include in parameters of hisMethod both the custom myMethod and the myMethod injected method that will never even be called? Or can I define a function parameter without specifying inputs with defaults